# The name does not exist in namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, kinect

I've been busy on a school project and I used the example of kinect toolkit for C# the interaction gallery.
The only peace of the interaction gallery we need was the pannable map.
this is my first c# project and I can't get around one single error.

The error is "*The name "Terminal1ContentModel" does not exist in the namespace.*"

```
"clr-namespace:Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.InteractionGallery.Models;assembly=InteractionGallery-WPF". C:***project 78\kinect\project\not_working_v8\kinect\InteractionGallery-WPF\Content\Terminal1ContentScreen\Terminal1.xaml
```

the code of `terminal1.xaml:`

```
    <Terminal1ContentModel xmlns="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.InteractionGallery.Models;assembly=InteractionGallery-WPF" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Terminal1ContentModel.ImageUri>
    <x:Uri>pack://application:,,,/Content/PannableContentScreen/PannableMapImage.jpg</x:Uri>
</Terminal1ContentModel.ImageUri>
```

and the code of the Terminal1ContentModel.cs is:

```
namespace Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.InteractionGallery.Models
{
   using System;
   public class Terminal1ContentModel
   {
       public Uri ImageUri { get; set; }
   }
}
```

I already closed and reopened visual studio and cleared my bin folder but those doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Reference the DLL in the solution.

Comment: from what I can find I don't use dll's....

Comment: THen reference them. The Kinekt is not part of any .NET framework default includes.

Comment: When I look in the reference folder it already includes microsoft.kinect and microsoft.kinect.toolkit.